# Want to connect to a cloud sql and display data from a table

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I want to connect to a clouds sql database and get data from a table in the database and display the values in the html webpage. I cant verify if this works because the console log didnt work for me. How can I show the result on the webpage.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');


function connectToDatabase() {
cost connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: '10.60.33.4'
        user: 'root',
        password: 'admin@1222',
        database: 'portal'
    });
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.connect(; resolve(connection);
    });
} {
function queryDatabase(connection)
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query('SELECT *
            FROM job_description ', (error, results,
            fields) => {
            resolve(results);
        });
});

function handlesql(){
return connectToDatabase()
then(connection => {
        return queryDatabase(connection)
        then(result => {
            res = result;
            connection.end():
        })
    }
    exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
        handlesql();
        let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || res;
        res.status(200).send(message);
    };
```

Comment: Hi Mike,Were the following recommendations helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You may choose from various options available to connect to Cloud SQL like using Cloud Run,Cloud Functions,App Engine and similar ones.
Please check the documentation for [SQL Connect](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions).
Once you have figured out the approach you want to go forward to connect to the Cloud SQL instance,complete the  setup for Cloud SQL instance .
As your code is using node js Cloud Functions , please check the following code snippet for the same to verify the details.

```
// createUnixSocketPool initializes a Unix socket connection pool for
// a Cloud SQL instance of MySQL.
const createUnixSocketPool = async config => {
  // Note: Saving credentials in environment variables is convenient, but not
  // secure - consider a more secure solution such as
  // Cloud Secret Manager (https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) to help
  // keep secrets safe.
  return mysql.createPool({
    user: process.env.DB_USER, // e.g. 'my-db-user'
    password: process.env.DB_PASS, // e.g. 'my-db-password'
    database: process.env.DB_NAME, // e.g. 'my-database'
    socketPath: process.env.INSTANCE_UNIX_SOCKET, // e.g. '/cloudsql/project:region:instance'
    // Specify additional properties here.
    ...config,
  });
};
```

Also , I would recommend you to check the [Git Hub Link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/main/cloud-sql/mysql/mysql/README.md) , for further information and a related approach.